# How to get the predictions of the textdata in fasttext python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

I am building a supervised model for text classification in fasttext.

To predict the output of a particular string we can use this in python

```
model.predict("Why not put knives in the dishwasher?")
```

But how to get the predictions for the whole test set by a python command? In the commandline it can be done like this

```
./fasttext predict <path to model> <path to test file> k > <path to prediction file>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
def predict(row):
    return model.predict(row['input'])
test['predictions'] = test.apply(predict,axis=1)
```